# Edit request in js before sending it to fullfillment endpoint

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I need to edit request before sending it to endpoint.

Using Web Demo integration I'm able to send request to the endpoint.
But I can't edit the request in order to provide some extra data to request. Extra data is stored in localStorage so I need to do this in javascript.

I've already connected the agent to an endpoint that handle the request using fullfillment. The problem is that request misses data I can retrieve only from the browser. From fullfillment I can set headers and basic auth but statically and it is not enough.

So I need to add a step in request building/sending:

1. User write or tell something to embedded chat (Web Demo integration)
2. Dialogflow recognize intent, params, generate the request.
3. Additional step: **Update the request in javascript**
4. Forward cutomized request to the endpoint

Maybe it's not possible using Web Demo integration. In [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2-overview) can't find a way to just send string or audio in order to receive the generated request.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need a custom chat integration, not the default Dialogflow one. Something like Smooch or Kommunicate. The default web demo should only be used for testing your bot. There is NO way you would want to use that in a production environment.

I would save whatever is in the local storage in a database such as Firestore. Once that data is in the database you can use it to modify your request in your fulfillment.

So what I would do:

1. Have a way to identify a user and save its local storage  to the database (as soon as someone clicks on your chat window or opens the chat window)
2. Once an intent is triggered you check which user is contacting you (through the way that you identified the user) and get all data from the database
3. Request the data in your fulfillment server

There is no other way in which this is possible. You can't change requests before your query hits Dialogflow.

Comment: please take a look at updated request, as I said I'm already able to reach an endpoint (using fullfillment), but the request should be update with data from user browser before it can be sent to the endpoint.

Comment: @assistbss I modified my answer ^

Comment: To be fair, I don't need a chat at all, I just need to send audio or text to dialogflow and I can't find the api to conversate with dialogflow. Documentation seems to cover just what you can do from console.dialogflow.com